# Bootloader Burning Issue

Tags: custom

I have a custom CCA that utilizes an ATMEGA328 but with an external clock of 1MHz that I originally burned the ADABOOT bootloader on using an Arduino Nano.  Everything worked as expected, only issue is I noticed the boot up time is a little long and after some research it seems that putting the Opti bootloader on may help with this.

Thus, I am trying to burn the opti bootloader onto my CCA, this time using an Elegoo Uno R3.  I successfully was able to upload the ArduinoISP sketch onto the Uno but when I go to burn the bootloader I get the following error:

```
avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM7
         Using Programmer              : stk500v1
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Error while burning bootloader.
```

I'm wondering if there is some sort of communication error since my custom CCA has the other bootloader on with different boards.txt settings than the default

f_cpu = 8000000L
upload speed = 7200
low fuse = 0XCB
high fuse = 0xDA
extended fuse = 0xFD

When I perform the loopback test I don't get an echo on the serial monitor.  I see both the "Rx" and "Tx" lights blink on the Uno, not sure if something is up there... Do you need to have a certain sketch uploaded for that to work?

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: did you select the programmer in Tools menu to "Arduino as ISP"?